# Display only the checkbox checked data on form submit

Tags: php, jquery, html-table

I have a form that consists of a table with four data cells for comparison in it and also each column has a check box. When I click on the checkbox and submit the form then I want to display only the checked tables in new page. How can I do that? Can anyone help me with working example?

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Comparision of Printers</title>

</head>
<body>

<form action="newpage.php" method="get">
<table width="1023" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td width="193"></td>
    <td class="p1" width="113"><img src="images/upmini.png"/>
      <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="p[]" value="Printer1" id="CheckboxGroup1_0" />
      Printer1</label>
</td>
    <td class="p2" width="67"><img  src="images/upmini.png"/>
      <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="p[]" value="Printer2" id="CheckboxGroup1_1" />
      Printer2</label></td>
    <td class="p3" width="67"><img  src="images/upmini.png"/><label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="p[]" value="Printer3" id="CheckboxGroup1_2" />
      Printer3</label></td>
    <td class="p4" width="67"><img  src="images/upmini.png"/><label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="p[]" value="Pritner4" id="CheckboxGroup1_3" />
      Printer4</label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Title</td>
    <td class="p1" >Printer1</td>
    <td class="p2" >Printer2</td>
    <td class="p3" >Printer3</td>
    <td class="p4" >Printer4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Manufacturer</td>
    <td class="p1" >Personal Portable 3DPrinters (PP3DP) founded by Be</td>
    <td class="p2" >Personal Portable 3DPrinters (PP3DP) founded by Be</td>
    <td class="p3" >Personal Portable 3DPrinters (PP3DP) founded by Be</td>
    <td class="p4" >Personal Portable 3DPrinters (PP3DP) founded by Be</td>
</tr>

</table>
<input type="submit" name="compare" value="compare" />
</form>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use `POST` instead of `GET` and store your `printer` and `manufacturer` information in a array. i use a 2D array to store the information to make it easy. and get the `key` values of this array in `GET REQUEST` and than print only those which match the keys. very simple..

this is full functional code ( changed little bit )

    
    
    
    Comparision of Printers

```
</head>
<body>
// store your infomation in a arrya and use KEY same as in your form checkbox name
<?php 
  $printers = array(
    'printer1' => array(
                    'title' => 'printer1',
                    'manufacturer' => 'Personal Portable 3DPrinters (PP3DP) founded by Be 1'
                  ),
    'printer3' => array(
                    'title' => 'printer2',
                    'manufacturer' => 'Personal Portable 3DPrinters (PP3DP) founded by Be 2'
                  ),
    'printer2' => array(
                    'title' => 'printer3',
                    'manufacturer' => 'Personal Portable 3DPrinters (PP3DP) founded by Be 3'
                  ),
    'printer4' => array(
                    'title' => 'printer4',
                    'manufacturer' => 'Personal Portable 3DPrinters (PP3DP) founded by Be 4'
                  ) 

    )
 ?>

 //if form submited then print the submited index only
<?php if(isset($_GET['p'])):?>
    <?php $printerIndex = $_GET['p'];?> 
    <table width="1023" border="1">
        <td>Title</td>
            <?php foreach($printerIndex as $index): ?>
                <td class = "p1" ><?php echo $printers[$index]['title']; ?></td>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Manufacturer</td>
          <?php foreach($printerIndex as $index): ?>
                <td class = "p1" ><?php echo $printers[$index]['manufacturer']; ?></td>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tr>
    </table> 
<?php endif; ?>

//make the table

<?php if(!isset($_GET['p'])): ?>
<form action="" method="get">
<table width="1023" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td width="193"></td>
        <?php foreach($printers as $printer ): ?>
        <td class="p1" width="113"><img src="images/upmini.png"/>
        <label> <?php echo $printer['title']; ?></label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="p[]" value="<?php echo $printer['title']; ?>" id="CheckboxGroup1_0" />
        </td>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tr>
<tr>
<td>Title</td>
    <?php foreach($printers as $printer): ?>
        <td class = "p1" ><?php echo $printer['title']; ?></td>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Manufacturer</td>
   <?php foreach($printers as $printer): ?>
       <td class = "p1" ><?php echo $printer['manufacturer']; ?></td>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
</tr>

</table>
<input type="submit" name="compare" value="compare" />
</form>
<?php endif; ?>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :). It solved my problem. +1 for this answer. Thanks once again.

Comment: glad to know..give +1 by vote up button 'at top left of this answer' if you can and mark it as accepted answer. thanks

Comment: I tried to mark it up but have got only 6 reputation. I need another 9 to mark it as good. Total i need 15 reputation.

Comment: Ok no problem do it when you have enough... enjoy stackOverflow

Answer (score 0):

The checked printers are stored as array `p` in the `$_GET` variable. Eg. checking printer 1 and 3 in your example will show the following result:

```
<?php var_dump($_GET) ?>

array
  'p' => 
    array
      0 => string 'Printer1' (length=8)
      1 => string 'Printer3' (length=8)
  'compare' => string 'compare' (length=7)
```

Comment: Hi, I can see the checked values in the newpage.php in the URL bar. But how can i display the checked tables only in the newpage.php????

Comment: for debugging purposes just use 'var_dump($_GET)' as in my example above.

Comment: To display the data in your template simply iterate over the `p` array. Something like that:
`foreach ($_GET['p'] as $printer) { echo $printer; }`

Comment: can you show me a working example please. Probably in Fiddle. Thanks

Comment: `<?php

if (isset($_GET['p']) && is_array($_GET['p'])) {
    
    echo '<p>Selected printers:</p>';
    
    foreach ($_GET['p'] as $printer) {
        
        echo '<p>' . $printer . '</p>';
    }    
}

?>`

Comment: Hi I can see that your example is display only the value of the checkbox. I am not looking for that answer. I want to display the entire table column eg. image, title and manufacturer. Is it possible to do like that? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have only ONE table with several TDs.

So within newpage.php you can do sth like:

```
if (isset($_GET['P']))
{ 
    $P = $_GET['P'];
    for ($i=0;$i<sizeof($P);$i++)
    {
        // Show what you like, e.g.
        echo "Printer".$P[$i]."<br />";
    }
}
```

Is it what you've meant?

Comment: No, I want to display the table data like title, manufacuturer on the checkbox checked condition. The question is straight forward.

Comment: @user2148257 Replace the class with name attributes, for e.g. p1_manufacturer, p2_manufacturer and so on. Then you can access the values with $_GET['p'.$P[$i].'_manufacturer'] like in my example. Do same with Title.